# Override host of webapi odata links

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

I'm using WebAPI 2.2 and Microsoft.AspNet.OData 5.7.0 to create an OData service that supports paging.

When hosted in the production environment, the WebAPI lives on a server that is not exposed externally, hence the various links returned in the OData response such as the `@odata.context` and `@odata.nextLink` point to the internal IP address e.g. `http://192.168.X.X/<AccountName>/api/...` etc.

I've been able to modify the `Request.ODataProperties().NextLink` by implementing some logic in each and every ODataController method to replace the internal URL with an external URL like `https://account-name.domain.com/api/...`, but this is very inconvenient and it only fixes the NextLinks.

Is there some way to set an external host name at configuration time of the OData service? I've seen a property `Request.ODataProperties().Path` and wonder if it's possible to set a base path at the `config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetModel());` call, or in the `GetModel()` implementation using for instance the `ODataConventionModelBuilder`?

---

**UPDATE:** The best solution I've come up with so far, is to create a `BaseODataController` that overrides the `Initialize` method and checks whether the `Request.RequestUri.Host.StartsWith("beginning-of-known-internal-IP-address")` and then do a RequestUri rewrite like so:

```
var externalAddress = ConfigClient.Get().ExternalAddress;  // e.g. https://account-name.domain.com
var account = ConfigClient.Get().Id;  // e.g. AccountName
var uriToReplace = new Uri(new Uri("http://" + Request.RequestUri.Host), account);
string originalUri = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
Request.RequestUri = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(uriToReplace.AbsoluteUri, externalAddress));
string newUri = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
this.GetLogger().Info($"Request URI was rewritten from {originalUri} to {newUri}");
```

This perfectly fixes the `@odata.nextLink` URLs for all controllers, but for some reason the `@odata.context` URLs still get the `AccountName` part (e.g. https://account-name.domain.com/AccountName/api/odata/$metadata#ControllerName) so they still don't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewriting the `RequestUri` is sufficient to affect `@odata.nextLink` values because the [code that computes the next link](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/Extensions/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs#L207) depends on the `RequestUri` directly. The other `@odata.xxx` links are computed via a [`UrlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx), which is *somehow* referencing the path from the original request URI. (Hence the `AccountName` you see in your `@odata.context` link. I've seen this behavior in my code, but I haven't been able to track down the source of the cached URI path.)

Rather than rewrite the `RequestUri`, we can solve the problem by creating a `CustomUrlHelper` class to rewrite OData links on the fly. The new `GetNextPageLink` method will handle `@odata.nextLink` rewrites, and the `Link` method override will handle all other rewrites.

```
public class CustomUrlHelper : System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper
{
    public CustomUrlHelper(HttpRequestMessage request) : base(request)
    { }

    // Change these strings to suit your specific needs.
    private static readonly string ODataRouteName = "ODataRoute"; // Must be the same as used in api config
    private static readonly string TargetPrefix = "http://localhost:8080/somePathPrefix"; 
    private static readonly int TargetPrefixLength = TargetPrefix.Length;
    private static readonly string ReplacementPrefix = "http://www.contoso.com"; // Do not end with slash

    // Helper method.
    protected string ReplaceTargetPrefix(string link)
    {
        if (link.StartsWith(TargetPrefix))
        {
            if (link.Length == TargetPrefixLength)
            {
                link = ReplacementPrefix;
            }
            else if (link[TargetPrefixLength] == '/')
            {
                link = ReplacementPrefix + link.Substring(TargetPrefixLength);
            }
        }

        return link;
    }

    public override string Link(string routeName, IDictionary<string, object> routeValues)
    {
        var link = base.Link(routeName, routeValues);

        if (routeName == ODataRouteName)
        {
            link = this.ReplaceTargetPrefix(link);
        }

        return link;
    }

    public Uri GetNextPageLink(int pageSize)
    {
        return new Uri(this.ReplaceTargetPrefix(this.Request.GetNextPageLink(pageSize).ToString()));
    }
}
```

Wire-up the `CustomUrlHelper` in the `Initialize` method of a base controller class.

```
public abstract class BaseODataController : ODataController
{
    protected abstract int DefaultPageSize { get; }

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        var helper = new CustomUrlHelper(controllerContext.Request);
        controllerContext.RequestContext.Url = helper;
        controllerContext.Request.ODataProperties().NextLink = helper.GetNextPageLink(this.DefaultPageSize);
    }
```

Note in the above that the page size will be the same for all actions in a given controller class. You can work around this limitation by moving the assignment of `ODataProperties().NextLink` to the body of a specific action method as follows:

```
var helper = this.RequestContext.Url as CustomUrlHelper;
this.Request.ODataProperties().NextLink = helper.GetNextPageLink(otherPageSize);
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising, and I've accepted your answer as solution. I think I've done something wrong in my implementation of it, because my service goes into an endless loop on the first request. The ODataController method gets called over and over again. I haven't got time to investigate it further right now, but I assume your solution will work if implemented correctly.

Comment: @lencharest this worked fine for outer next page links however when we use an expand on the query filter the inner nested collection has a next page link which doesn't work instead it just comes out as https://serviceurl/odata?skip=25

Answer (score 6):

The answer by lencharest is promising, but I found an improvement on his method.  Rather than using the UrlHelper, I created a class derived from System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.  This class is inserted (first) into the message handling pipeline and thus has a crack at altering the incoming HttpRequestMessage.  It's an improvement over the above solution because in addition to altering the controller-specific URLs (as the UrlHelper does, e,g, https://data.contoso.com/odata/MyController), it also alters the url that appears as the xml:base in the OData service document (e.g., https://data.contoso.com/odata).

My particular application was to host an OData service behind a proxy server, and I wanted all the URLs presented by the server to be the externally-visible URLs, not the internally-visible ones.  And, I didn't want to have to rely on annotations for this; I wanted it to be fully automatic.

The message handler looks like this:

```
    public class BehindProxyMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var builder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);
            var visibleHost = builder.Host;
            var visibleScheme = builder.Scheme;
            var visiblePort = builder.Port;

            if (request.Headers.Contains("X-Forwarded-Host"))
            {
                string[] forwardedHosts = request.Headers.GetValues("X-Forwarded-Host").First().Split(new char[] { ',' });
                visibleHost = forwardedHosts[0].Trim();
            }

            if (request.Headers.Contains("X-Forwarded-Proto"))
            {
                visibleScheme = request.Headers.GetValues("X-Forwarded-Proto").First();
            }

            if (request.Headers.Contains("X-Forwarded-Port"))
            {
                try
                {
                    visiblePort = int.Parse(request.Headers.GetValues("X-Forwarded-Port").First());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            }

            builder.Host = visibleHost;
            builder.Scheme = visibleScheme;
            builder.Port = visiblePort;

            request.RequestUri = builder.Uri;
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

You wire the handler up in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "odata",
        routePrefix: "odata",
        model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
        pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
        routingConventions: ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault()
    );
    config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new BehindProxyMessageHandler());
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of years later, using ASP.NET Core, I figured that the easiest way to apply it in my service was to just create a filter that masquerades the host name. (`AppConfig` is a custom configuration class that contains the host name, among other things.)

```
public class MasqueradeHostFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var appConfig = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<AppConfig>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appConfig?.MasqueradeHost))
            context.HttpContext.Request.Host = new HostString(appConfig.MasqueradeHost);
    }
}
```

Apply the filter to the controller base class.

```
[MasqueradeHostFilter]
public class AppODataController : ODataController
{
}
```

The result is a nicely formatted output:

```
{ "@odata.context":"https://app.example.com/odata/$metadata" }
```

Just my two cents.

Comment: It can also be done with .NET Framework: `context.ControllerContext.Request.RequestUri = new Uri(...)`. I set the filter globally with `config.Filters.Add(new MasqueradeHostFilterAttribute());` in `WebApiConfig.Register`. Reading the `X-Forwarded-Host` header can be useful for automatically using the proxy's URL.

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution, but it overrides url for the entire context.
What I'd like to suggest is:

1. Create owin middleware and override Host and Scheme properties inside
2. Register the middleware as the first one

Here is an example of middleware

```
public class RewriteUrlMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public RewriteUrlMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Host = new HostString(Settings.Default.ProxyHost);
        context.Request.Scheme = Settings.Default.ProxyScheme;
        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

ProxyHost is the host you want to have. Example: test.com

ProxyScheme is the scheme you want: Example: https

Example of middleware registration

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(typeof(RewriteUrlMiddleware));
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using system.web.odata 6.0.0.0.

Setting the NextLink property too soon is problematic. Every reply will then have a nextLink in it. The last page should of course be free of such decorations.

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-os.html#_Toc372793048 says:

> URLs present in a payload (whether request or response) MAY be
>   represented as relative URLs.

One way that I hope will work is to override EnableQueryAttribute:

```
public class myEnableQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var result = base.ApplyQuery(queryable, queryOptions);
        var nextlink = queryOptions.Request.ODataProperties().NextLink;
        if (nextlink != null)
            queryOptions.Request.ODataProperties().NextLink = queryOptions.Request.RequestUri.MakeRelativeUri(nextlink);
        return result;
    }
}
```

`ApplyQuery()` is where the "overflow" is detected. It basically asks for `pagesize+1` rows and will set `NextLink` if the result set contains more than `pagesize` rows.

At this point it is relatively easy to rewrite `NextLink` to a relative URL.

The downside is that every odata method must now be adorned with the new myEnableQuery attribute:

```
[myEnableQuery]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<TElement> options)
{
  ...
}
```

and other URLs embedded elsewhere remains problematic. odata.context remains a problem. I want to avoid playing with the request URL, because I fail to see how that is maintainable over time.

Answer (score -1):

Your question boils down to controlling the service root URI from within the service itself. My first thought was to look for a hook on the media type formatters used to serialize responses. `ODataMediaTypeFormatter.MessageWriterSettings.PayloadBaseUri` and `ODataMediaTypeFormatter.MessageWriterSettings.ODataUri.ServiceRoot` are both settable properties that suggest a solution. Unfortunately, `ODataMediaTypeFormatter` [resets](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/ODataMediaTypeFormatter.cs#L502) these properties on every call to [`WriteToStreamAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.formatter.odatamediatypeformatter.writetostreamasync(v=vs.118).aspx).

The work-around is not obvious, but if you dig through the source code you'll eventually reach a call to `IODataPathHandler.Link`. A path handler is an OData extension point, so you can create a custom path handler that always returns an absolute URI which begins with the service root you desire.

```
public class CustomPathHandler : DefaultODataPathHandler
{
    private const string ServiceRoot = "http://example.com/";

    public override string Link(ODataPath path)
    {
        return ServiceRoot + base.Link(path);
    }
}
```

And then register that path handler during service configuration.

```
// config is an instance of HttpConfiguration
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "ODataRoute",
    routePrefix: null,
    model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
    pathHandler: new CustomPathHandler(),
    routingConventions: ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault()
);
```

Comment: This looks like the configuration solution I'm looking for. I'll test it on monday.

Comment: This seems to replace what comes after the service root for some reason. So my @odata.context now becomes "@odata.context": "http://localhost/api/edi/odata/https://AaccountName.domain.com/$metadata#DeliveryNotes".

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you. I am running on a Mac under OWIN. Just guessing, but that may be the source of the difference.

Comment: On a Mac? Then it must be ASP.NET Core 1. Maybe they've changed the way ODataPath works in the upcoming version.